# Angular Prod build missing lodash

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lodash

My app uses lodash selectively just about everywhere. Example:

```
import { keyBy as _keyBy, orderBy as _orderBy, map as _map, sample as _sample } from 'lodash';
```

Everything works great in development. However, in production it breaks with the following error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: lodash_1 is not defined

Heres my production build config:

```
"production": {
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure why this is failing. I dont know if a handful of other 3rd party libraries would fail because the app crashes right on load.

**Edit**
I have lodash included in my dependencies, not devDependencies. 
I'm lazy loading modules. I never had this issue when I wasnt lazy loading.

I just turned off AOT off and the build works fine.

**Updated Question** Why/how would AOT break 3rd party imports, namely lodash?

Comment: Make sure you have lodash in dependencies in package.json not in devDependencies

Comment: Yup. Check my edit.

Comment: have you included lodash script from node_modules/ into `angular.json` file in `scripts` field ?

Answer (score 0):

usually it's an indicator of missing types, so try to install "@types/lodash"

add it to your package.json

```
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.121",
```

or do

```
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev
```